# Ruby multi threading #join and simultaneous execution

Tags: ruby, multithreading

My records in a database are already categorized into buckets (0, 1, 2, 3). Rather than applying a function to each record serially, I'd like to open four threads and apply the function to the record in that thread's bucket.

If I run this:

```
i = 4
i.times do |n|
  Thread.new {
    puts "opening thread for #{n} degree"
    myFunction(n)
  }.join
end
```

I get:

```
opening thread for 0 degree
opening thread for 1 degree
opening thread for 2 degree
opening thread for 3 degree
```

with waiting in between each one. It's still going serially.

If I do the same as above, but without `join`:

```
i = 4
i.times do |n|
  Thread.new {
    puts "opening thread for #{n} degree"
    myFunction(n)
  }
end
```

I get:

```
opening thread for 3 degree
opening thread for 2 degreeopening thread for 0 degree
opening thread for 4 degree
```

which is closer to what I want; it seems they all run simultaneously.

It makes me nervous when my puts statements are printed haphazardly like this. If I don't have the `join` there, doesn't that mean that whichever thread terminates first, the rest of the script moves on and the other threads terminate early? What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What SHOULD I be doing here?

You should be joining your threads. Otherwise when the main thread (your script) exits, it takes all unfinished threads with it. The reason why execution is serial in your first case is that you wait for a thread to finish right after you start it (and **before you start the next one**). First create all threads, then wait on them.

```
i = 4
threads = i.times.map do |n|
  Thread.new {
    puts "opening thread for #{n} degree"
    myFunction(n)
  }
end

threads.each(&:join)
# or
require 'thwait'
ThreadsWait.all_waits(*threads)
```

You will see further improvements in threading performance if you run the code on JRuby or Rubinius, as their threads are not crippled in any way by some global lock.